# Json Deserialization of "2017-09-11 14:28:42" fails with 'while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'''

Tags: java, json, date

there are still some similar threads but I think this is another situation.

I am trying to deserialize a date-string from JSON:

> '2017-09-11 14:28:42' (without Z)

In my Json File the property is of type java.util.Date and is annotated with:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Europe/Berlin")
```

Although I am getting this error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2017-09-11 14:28:42": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-09-11 14:28:42': Can not parse date "2017-09-11 14:28:42Z": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'', parsing fails (leniency? null))

Why the hell it is making "2017-09-11 14:28:42Z" of my original string "2017-09-11 14:28:42". Why does it add this 'Z'?
In other threads the solution was to use @JsonFormat or to remove this 'Z' from the String. Well I am still using @JsonFormat and there originally is no 'Z' in the String.

When requesting the resource with postman I am getting this value for the concerned property:

> ```
>     "deviceStatusSince": "2017-09-11 14:28:42",
> ```

Any help would be grateful.

Edit#1
Full StackTrace:

```
E/ASYNCTASKLOADDEVICEFROM: Deserialization of response failed! response: [{"id":4,"deviceId":"abc123def","deviceName":"mymachinename","deviceType":"mymachinetype","deviceStatus":1,"deviceStatusSince":"2017-09-11 14:28:42","location":"somewhere","created":"2019-01-24 19:25:11","updated":"2019-01-24 19:25:11","lamport_timestamp":3},{"id":5,"deviceId":"abc123def","deviceName":"mymachinename","deviceType":"mymachinetype","deviceStatus":1,"deviceStatusSince":"2017-09-11 14:28:42","location":"somewhere","created":"2019-01-24 20:10:29","updated":"2019-01-24 20:10:29","lamport_timestamp":3}]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "2017-09-11 14:28:42": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-09-11 14:28:42': Can not parse date "2017-09-11 14:28:42Z": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'', parsing fails (leniency? null))
    at [Source: (String)"[{"id":4,"deviceId":"5123b85f316a9_01","deviceName":"Maschine #123","deviceType":"mymachinetype","deviceStatus":1,"deviceStatusSince":"2017-09-11 14:28:42","location":"somewhere","created":"2019-01-24 19:25:11","updated":"2019-01-24 19:25:11","lamport_timestamp":3},{"id":5,"deviceId":"abc123def","deviceName":"mymachinename","deviceType":"mymachinetype","deviceStatus":1,"deviceStatusSince":"2017-09-11 14:28:42","location":"somewhere","created":"2019-01-24 20:10:29","updated":"[truncated 45 chars]; line: 1, column: 135] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->my.project.models.json.DeviceJson["deviceStatusSince"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1504)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:910)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:513)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:466)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateBasedDeserializer._parseDate(DateDeserializers.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:268)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3999)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2999)
    at my.project.remote.async.AsyncTaskLoadDevicesFromServer.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoadDevicesFromServer.java:147)
    at my.project.remote.async.AsyncTaskLoadDevicesFromServer.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoadDevicesFromServer.java:46)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    E/ASYNCTASKLOADDEVICEFROM:     at                 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Edit#2:
When setting the property to null it works. But I want to notice that properties created and updated are configured similarily (@JsonAnnotation, same pattern, same String). Whats different there, what do I not see?

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Europe/Berlin") private Date created;
```

Edit#3:
This is the response used to be deserialized via objectMapper.readValue:

```
[{"id":8,"deviceId":"abc123def","deviceName":"mymachine","deviceType":"mymachinetype","deviceStatus":1,"deviceStatusSince":"2017-09-10 13:37:42","location":"somewhere","created":"2019-01-26 01:09:06","updated":"2019-01-26 01:09:06","lamport_timestamp":3}]
```

Comment: Your pattern expects a `'T'` separating date from time, your input doesn't have it.

Comment: @ernest_k: I don't see a T in the input format in the annotation...

Comment: I think this is not true. My pattern expects a space not 'T'. even when I change my pattern to ''pattern="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" it does not change anything to the result.

Comment: Please could you provide the full stack trace rather than just the type and message? That may well make it easier to trace what's adding the Z.

Comment: Why are you using the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` class? Could the modern `LocalDateTime` and [FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) be a solution?

Comment: stacktrace added
this is a long running project getting just an extension, we are trying to stay minimally invasive. And as to see on created/updated fields it seems to work in earlier entities.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "And as to see on created/updated fields it seems to work in earlier entities." That may be very useful in working out what's going on, but I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: The `Z` is stands for Zulu/Zero, Greenwich Mean Time. Maybe because of the `timezone` parameter having been set. That might have added a Z because of a failed time zone recognition. `CET`? _(Having no experience with this usage)_

Comment: Use , timezone = JsonFormat.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE, or TimeZone.getDefault()

Comment: changing the timezone does not help. See my 2nd edit, there also hibernate fields for created and updated. These are deserialized in the same way as the problem-field. they are (like i would say) exactly defined as the problem-field too. Why do they work when setting the field to null? Why are the fields created and updated deserialized correctly and why does that not work with the field deviceStatusSince?

Comment: as workaround I am using String instead of Date for deserialization. Still weird why it does not work like the created-field. I think there is a random bug in the ObjectMapper which expects a Timezone although the date is without timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated another field by copying from the created field and deleted the status field mentioned here. The new field worked, i renamed it then.
Maybe an invisible sign was the cause, I dont know.